# Redis sessionID from Jedis

Tags: java, redis

How can I get an ID of a session, after connecting to Redis through one if its clients, or with Jedis in my case?

After instantiating Jedis and calling connect(), I need some kind of session ID back.

Or how can I store a previously generated UUID as a value for a given key?

Answer (score 1):

See http://redis.io/commands/client-setname

With this command you give a connection a name, that later can be queried or listed.